# CDF on subset of real line is continuous if it has no atoms?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, continuity

Is the claim in the title true? If so, can someone link or provide a proof? Also, out of curiosity, if the claim is true for the real line, is it true for $\mathbb{R}^n$, or some more general spaces?

For example, Consider the subset  $[0,2]\subset \mathbb{R}$, and a cdf $F$ on this subset. We know the limit from the right of $F$ exists and equals $F(x)$ (we approaching $x$). So we just have to show that if $F$ has no atoms then the limit from the left approaching $x$ is $F(x)$.

This seems trivial but I can't think of how to formally write it. (Intuitively, the function can't suddenly "jump up" at the limit.

Comment: A cdf is *[càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)*.  The left and right limits are the same at at $x$ iff the cdf is continuous at $x$. The left and right limits are different at $x$ iff there is an atom at $x$.  So if the cdf is continuous everywhere iff there are no atoms,

Comment: Any update about whether this is true in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable with cdf $F$. Every cdf is right continuous at every point $x$ since $(X\leq x+n^{-1})\downarrow (X\leq x)$ so
$$
F(x)=P(X\le x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X\le x+n^{-1})=\lim_{y\downarrow x}F(y)
$$
by measure continuity from above. Similarly, $(X\leq x-1/n)\uparrow (X\lt x)$ whence
$$
P(X<x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X\le x-n^{-1})=\lim_{y\uparrow x}F(y)=F(x-)$$
by measure continuity from below. Now observe that
$$
P(X=x)=P(X\leq x)-P(X<x)=F(x)-F(x-)
$$
Thus $P(X=x)=0$ iff $F(x+)=F(x)=F(x-)$ i.e. iff $F$ is continuous at $x$.